# Service.startForeground vibrates the device

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-notifications

I'm using the [startForeground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) call for one of my Services:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notifBuilder = 
                              new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "my_channel")
                              .setContentTitle("Loading");
startForeground(1, notifBuilder.build());
```

The problem is that since I'm using my unique channel for notifications and it has vibration:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =
      (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationChannel mChannel = 
        new NotificationChannel("my_channel", "Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAUL);
mChannel.enableLights(true);
mChannel.enableVibration(true);
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
```

The `startForeground()` call generates vibration.

Tried some configs:

Not working:`notifBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0,0})` nor `notifBuilder.setDefaults(~Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)`

Working on my device `notifBuilder.setVibrate(null)` or using a non-registered channel id but I'm not sure if this can cause crashes in other versions or devices.

How can I avoid this vibration without declaring a new channel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating the `NotificationChannel` with `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` which the documentation says:

> Default notification importance: shows everywhere, makes noise, but does not visually intrude.

You probably want `IMPORTANCE_LOW`:

> Low notification importance: shows everywhere, but is not intrusive.

If you want `"my_channel"` to stay `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`, you can create a new channel with a different importance for this service.

Answer (score 1):

The vibration pattern is specific to that notification channel, so you'd have to disable it on the notification channel when you post the notification, then reenabled it for notifications you'd like to have vibrate.  You could also have separate notification channels for different priorities, as hinted to in the docs:

```
When you target Android 8.0 (API level 26), you must implement one or more notification channels to display notifications to your users.
```

So, even if you used setVibrate(null), or some other variation, it'll just be ignored on 26+, since that method has been deprecated and the NotificationChannel's pattern will now be used:

```
/**
 * The pattern with which to vibrate.
 *
 * <p>
 * To vibrate the default pattern, see {@link #defaults}.
 * </p>
 *
 * @see android.os.Vibrator#vibrate(long[],int)
 * @deprecated use {@link NotificationChannel#getVibrationPattern()}.
 */
@Deprecated
public long[] vibrate;
```